# How to make a OR statement in group?

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression that matches first long, second long and third string.
I created a regular expression in below but it only matches for first example. I tried `|` OR statement but couldn't done it. Any ideas?

My regular expression:

```
(\d+),(\d+),\"(.*)\"
```

Examples:

```
1. 85327872,85360639,"AS43754 Asiatech Data Transfer Inc. PLC"
2. 85360640,85360895,AS65010
```

Comment: I don't see an OR in there at all. Also, this has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: what are you trying to extract?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes but when I do it selects quotation marks too. I don't want quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `\"?` will say may or not contain a quote. Then, inside your matching group use `[^"\n]` that means: any character, except quotes or a new line.

`(\d+),(\d+),\"?([^"\n]*)`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/xI4gO9/3)

---

The previous regex evolved by some comments into:

`(\d+),(\d+),\"?(.+?)"?$`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/xI4gO9/5)

Comment: I beg your pardon, I couldn't comment days ago when this answer was accepted. I just wonder... I guess this allows for weird things like opening " without closing it at the end of the string. the OP provided two examples but none of them had such case. am I wrong, paranoid or just quite bothering :) ?

Comment: @Leo128. You are right, but doesn't it looks weird to you? _https://regex101.com/r/xI4gO9/4_

Comment: yes it is indeed weird... and what if one row spells 85327872,85360639,AS43754 Asiatech "Data" Transfer Inc. PLC? This is the reason why in my answer I suggested the OP to decide either to keep or remove those quotes as string start/end delimiters... Did I manage to show my point?

Comment: Thank you @Leo128. I think this could help: `(\d+),(\d+),\"?(.+?)"?$` .. https://regex101.com/r/xI4gO9/5

Comment: exact. now you are getting me convenced. I suppose this should be the best answer, or an addition to it.